# Process.Plugin to Invocable Method in the Apex Classes

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, action, invocable-method

We are currently using the Apex Class with Process.Plugin that is refered here in the article https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/03/visual-workflow-converting-leads-with-an-apex-plugin.html

```
// Converts a lead as a step in a Visual Workflow process
global class VWFConvertLead implements Process.Plugin {
    // This method runs when the step is reached in a Flow
    global Process.PluginResult invoke(Process.PluginRequest request) {
        // set up variables to store input parameters from the Flow
        String leadID = (String) request.inputParameters.get('LeadID');
        String contactID = (String) request.inputParameters.get('ContactID');
        String accountID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; /*New Contact Account by Default*/ /*(String) request.inputParameters.get('AccountID');*/
        String convertedStatus = (String) request.inputParameters.get('ConvertedStatus');
        Boolean overWriteLeadSource = false; /*(Boolean) request.inputParameters.get('OverwriteLeadSource');*/
        Boolean createOpportunity = false; /*(Boolean) request.inputParameters.get('CreateOpportunity');*/
        String opportunityName = ''; /*(String) request.inputParameters.get('ContactID');*/ 
        Boolean sendEmailToOwner = false; /*(Boolean) request.inputParameters.get('SendEmailToOwner');   */
        String leadCompany = (String) request.inputParameters.get('LeadCompany');
        
        Map<String,Object> result = new Map<String,Object>();
        result = convertLead(leadID, contactID, accountID, convertedStatus, overWriteLeadSource, createOpportunity, opportunityName, sendEmailToOwner, leadCompany);
 
        return new Process.PluginResult(result); 
    }
    

    global Process.PluginDescribeResult describe() {
        // Set up plugin metadata
        Process.PluginDescribeResult result = new Process.PluginDescribeResult();
        result.description = 'The LeadConvert Flow Plug-in converts a lead into an account and contact, as well as (optionally) an opportunity.';
        result.tag = 'Lead Management';
        
        result.inputParameters = new List<Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter>{
            // Lead ID (mandatory)
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('LeadID', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, true),
            // Account Id (optional)
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('AccountID', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, false),
            // Contact ID (optional)
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('ContactID', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, false),            
            // Status to use once converted
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('ConvertedStatus', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, true),
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('OpportunityName', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, false),
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('OverwriteLeadSource', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.BOOLEAN, false),
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('CreateOpportunity', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.BOOLEAN, false),
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('SendEmailToOwner', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.BOOLEAN, false),
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('leadCompany', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, false)
        };

        // Create a list that stores *output* parameters sent *to* your flow.
        result.outputParameters = new List<Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter>{
            // Account ID of the converted lead
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter('AccountID', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING),
            // Contact ID of the converted lead
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter('ContactID', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING),
            // Opportunity ID of the converted lead
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter('OpportunityID', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING),
            // Company Name of the lead before converted
            new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter('LeadCompanyName', 
                    Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING)   
        };

        return result;
    }
        
 
    public Map<String,String> convertLead (
                               String leadID,
                               String contactID,
                               String accountID,
                               String convertedStatus,
                               Boolean overWriteLeadSource,
                               Boolean createOpportunity,
                               String opportunityName,
                               Boolean sendEmailToOwner,
                               String leadCompany
        ) {
        Map<String,String> result = new Map<String,String>();
                                
        if (leadId == null) throw new ConvertLeadPluginException('Lead Id cannot be null');
        
        // check for multiple leads with the same ID
        Lead[] leads = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Company From Lead where Id = :leadID];
        if (leads.size() > 0) {
            Lead l = leads[0];
            // CheckAccount = true, checkContact = false
            if (accountID == null && l.Company != null) {
                Account[] accounts = [Select Id, Name FROM Account where Name = :l.Company LIMIT 1];
                if (accounts.size() > 0) {
                    accountId = accounts[0].id;
                }
            }
            
            // perform the lead conversion
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(leadID);
            lc.setOverwriteLeadSource(overWriteLeadSource);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(!createOpportunity);
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertedStatus);
            if (sendEmailToOwner != null) lc.setSendNotificationEmail(sendEmailToOwner);
            if (accountId != null && accountId.length() > 0) lc.setAccountId(accountId);
            if (contactId != null && contactId.length() > 0) lc.setContactId(contactId);
            /*if (createOpportunity) {
                lc.setOpportunityName(opportunityName);
            }*/                                    
            
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc, true);
            if (lcr.isSuccess()) {
                /*Contact newContact = [SELECT Id, Company_Name_from_Form_Webinar__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: lcr.getContactID()];
                newContact.Company_Name_from_Form_Webinar__c = leadCompany;
                update newContact;*/
                
                result.put('AccountID', lcr.getAccountId());
                result.put('ContactID', lcr.getContactId());
                result.put('LeadCompanyName', leadCompany);
                /*if (createOpportunity) {
                    result.put('OpportunityID', lcr.getOpportunityId());
                }*/
            } 
            else {
                String error = lcr.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                throw new ConvertLeadPluginException(error);
            }
        } 
        else { 
            throw new ConvertLeadPluginException('No leads found with Id : "' + leadId + '"');
        }
        return result;
    }
        
        // Utility exception class
        class ConvertLeadPluginException extends Exception {}
}
```

Looks like with Spring 21 that the **Make Flows Respect Access Modifiers for Legacy Apex Action** we need to replace all the Process.Plugin to the InvocableMethod annotation. Also I can see in the flow that calls this action throws error

[image]

Can anyone help how can we convert the existing the apex to use @InvocableMethod. Any recommendations if there is any replacement of this action

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a wrapper class that describes your input and output parameters, much like the original describe method:

```
global class ConvertLeadRequest {
  @InvocableVariable(required=true) global Id LeadID;
  @InvocableVariable Id AccountID;
  // etc //
}
global class ConvertLeadResult {
  // Whatever you need here //
}
```

Then, you need your main class:

```
global class ConvertLeadAction {
  global class ConvertLeadRequest {
    // from above example //
  }
  global class ConvertLeadResult {
    // from above example //
  @InvocableMethod(label='Convert Lead Action')
  global static List<ConvertLeadResult> convertLeads(List<ConvertLeadRequest> requests) {
    // Handle input, convert leads, and then return output //
  }
}
```

Note that I basically just borrowed this [from the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm), which has a literal example of doing what you're trying to do.

I do not recommend throwing an exception, though; you must return an appropriate error message or something. This is required because these methods are bulkified; multiple requests can be triggered at once (e.g. during bulk data loads), so your code needs to be prepared to handle this situation.